# Certificate Authority - Issuing Authority Confusion

Tags: ssl-certificate

This is a bit of a newbie question, but my head is fried after reading various differing article on how CA's work.

Are most certificates issued by an 'intermediate CA' where the chain eventually leads back to a root CA?

So for example, if I request a certificate from VeriSign, do they delegate the task to an Intermediate CA to 'distribute' the issuing of certificates?

My certificate would then be verified with the Intermediate certificate which in turn would be verified by the Root CA, completing the authentication chain?

If this is the case, is there ever a situation where the Root CA will issue a certificate directly to a company/organisation that has requested a certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the most common model for public CA's, mostly because the "root ca" is usually offline. You can't steal the key / or compromise a machine if it's offline. (at least not over the network)

Also, if the intermediate (issuing) CA get's compromised, the CA *could* just revoke that sub-ca, without having to deal with getting a new Root CA backed into all browsers and stuff.

There can very well be situations where you receive certificates signed directly from a Root CA, but it's not common amongst the "Trusted Public Root CA's" out there AFAIK.